# I can only access my SFTP Server at home

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, sftp

recently setup my SFTP server on Ubuntu and I connect to my Ubuntu server on a Windows machine running Windows 10 using WinSCP.

Now i can connect using WinSCP with no issues once I'm inside my private network but lets say if i wanted to connect to my laptop outside my network it doesn't work.

After researching online I believe the issue is port forwarding so i went into my router and added the port 22 that needs to be open for SSH (SFTP)
after applying the settings to my ip address it doesnt seem to work at all, it only works if im connect to my private network.

I have ran port check and it says its open using www.portchecktool.com so I'm not too sure what else i need to do

any help would be great thank you

Comment: perhaps your firewall or SSH config is stopping external access to your machine? Can you SSH in from an external network?

Comment: You may need to simply use another port. Anecdotally, I have had similar issues (ISP doesn't block 22, port forwarding set correctly, firewalls open but still can't connect) and using another port solved this instantly.

Comment: What IP address are you using to connect to it? When you're on the outside, you need to use the router's external IP address (and let it forward to the server's private address).

Comment: I did think it was my firewall causing the issue so i turned it off i tried adding inbound rules in advanced settings but that still didnt work.

I cant ssh into my PC from an external network either which is  strange as i setup my DDNS so that my public IP could just use my DNS to point to my PC but that didnt work..

possibly could try changing ports how would i change ports on file zilla or on ubuntu ssh? like in my sshd_config?

as for my IP address its 192.168.1.5 that the ip adress im trying to use both externally and on my network.

Comment: I just found out how to change the port for my ssh server running on ubuntu tested the port it wasnt open, so i went in and forwarded the port I choose port 25 now thats open, unfortunately when I go in and try and connect to the server still get the same error and it times out.